# Is there any possibility to simplify the nested condition into non nested in C#?

Tags: c#, if-statement, nested, simplify

I have 3 conditions to check before returning true or false.
Here is the table:

[image]

This can be achieved using below logic

```
if(!COND1 && !COND2)
{
    if(COND3)
    {
        return False
    }
    else
    {
        return True
    }
}
else
{
    return true
}
```

Can this be simplified without using nested *if* ?

Comment: Sure. That particular table reduces to return (!cond1 || !cond2 || cond3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write it:

```
if (a && b && !c)
{
    return false;
}
return true;
```

or simply:

```
return !(a && b && !c)
```